# Is 'in' operator "lazy" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I do this, does `split()` get called for each iteration?:

```
a = [word for word in post.split() if len(word) > 10]
```

Should I do this instead for better performance?

```
s = post.split()
a = [word for word in s if len(word) > 10]
```

Comment: This is not what "lazy" means.

Comment: @vartec Would you mind to explain it a bit more, or is it a completely different topic?

Comment: That's not actually the `in` operator. It's a `for ... in ...` clause in a list comprehension which is not at all the same thing, despite using the same keyword.

Comment: "Should I do this instead for better performance?" You could've answered that by simply trying it. This website is not your personal performance testing service.

Comment: @sooqua https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

Comment: It's a shame this is the top search result for the title, because it would actually be interesting to know if `in` forces evaluation of an entire iterator or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single expression is fine - `post.split()` will only be called once.

This is because a `for` loop in Python *iterates* through the values of your object supporting iteration - it doesn't keep checking against some conditional statement which you might see in another language, like looping through an array in C.

So in this case, `post.split()` produces your object which the `for` loop then iterates through, and need not be called again.

---

"*lazy*"-ness is also not the right terminology to be asking about here, as it refers to the practice of delaying expression evaluation until it is strictly needed. Here we certainly *need* to call `post.split()`, and the question is more a matter of "*efficiency*". See [Lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) on Wiki for a good description of the strategy.

Answer (score 3):

`post.split()` is called only once. You can verify it by replacing `post.split()` with a function that print every time when it is called:

```
>>> post = 'a b c d'
>>> def split_post():
...     print('split_post is called')
...     return post.split()
... 
>>> a = [word for word in split_post() if len(word) > 10]
split_post is called
```

You don't need to divide the expression into two statement for performance.